# React-table exclude default column filter

Tags: react-table, react-table-v7, react-table-v6

I have a default column filter and I'm wondering if there is a way from excluding it from one column.
You can check an example from React-table that I'm using: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering

The 'DefaultColumnFilter' is being used in useTable hook and all columns are using it by default

Is there a way from excluding one column from using it?

Answer (score 4):

Two options -

1. If you don't want the given column to have filters, then use `disableFilters` flag on that column in options.
2. If you want to have different type of filter for the given column, then use `Filter` property in the given column(as shown in provided example)